# What encoding/compression algorithm is this?

Tags: string, encoding, compression, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer a binary file format, but it has no magic bytes, and no specific extension. I can influence only a single aspect of the file: *a short string*. By trying different strings, I was able to figure out how data is stored in the file. It seems that the whole file uses some sort of simple encoding. I hope that finding the exact encoding allows me to narrow down my search for the file format. I know the file is generated by a Windows program written in C++.

Now, after much trial-and-error, I found that some sections of the file are encoded in *runs*. Each run starts with a byte that indicates how many bytes will follow and where the data is retrieved.

- `000ddddd` (1 byte)
  Take the following (ddddd)+1 bytes from the encoded data.
- `111·····  ···ddddd  ···bbbbb` (3 bytes)
  Go back (bbbbb)+1 bytes in the decoded data, and take the next (ddddd)+9 bytes from it.
- `ddd·····  ··bbbbbb` (2 bytes)
  Go back (bbbbbb)+1 bytes in the decoded data, and take the next (ddd)+2 bytes from it.

Here's an example:

> This is the start of the file, with the UTF-16 string `abracadabra` encoded in it:
>
> [image: First 224 bytes of the file]
>
> ```
>   .     .  .  a  .  b  .  r     .  .  c     .  .  d     .  €  .
>   0C 20 03 04 61 00 62 00 72 20 05 00 63 20 03 00 64 20 03 80 0D
> ```
>
> To decode the string:
>
> ```
>   0C                      number of Unicode chars: 12 (11 chars + \0)
>   20 03       . . .       ??
>   04                      next 5
>   61 00       a .
>   62 00       b .
>   72          r
>   20 05       . a .       back 6, take 3
>   00                      next 1
>   63          c
>   20 03       . a .       back 4, take 3
>   00                      next 1
>   64          d
>   20 03       . a .       back 4, take 3
>   80 0D       b . r . a . back 14, take 6
> ```
>
> This results in (UTF-16):
>
> ```
>   a  .  b  .  r  .  a  .  c  .  a  .  d  .  a  .  b  .  r  .  a  .
>   61 00 62 00 72 00 61 00 63 00 61 00 64 00 61 00 62 00 72 00 61 00
> ```

However, I have *no* clue as to what encoding/compression algorithm this might be. It looks like some variant of LZ that doesn't use a dictionary (like LZ77), but so far I haven't been able to find any algorithm that matches this description. I'm also not sure whether the entire file is encoded like this, or only portions of it.

*Do you know this encoding? Or do you have any hints for things I might look for in the file to identify the encoding?*

Comment: Are you sure the file contains text?

Comment: @Hidde I can command the program to give me a big file with a particular 18 character string in it that I choose. These are the strings that I chose, and their corresponding encoded versions in the resulting file. I haven't been able to find any other strings in the binary file, but that may be due to the encoding.

Comment: It appears the first byte is the length of your string in hexidecimal.

Comment: If this encoding is for compression, it would have to win the prize for worst compression approach, _ever!_

Comment: @MarkAdler While searching for this encoding, I came across LZ77. It encodes a match as an offset backwards, length, and a character that follows it. This takes up _three bytes_ per match. However, a non-match is also considered a match (0 offset, 0 size), taking up three bytes. So, in the worst case, your string takes up _three times as many bytes_. :P

Comment: Please provide the result for an empty string, a single character, and a single non-ASCII character (i.e. something that requires UTF-8 or UTF-16 to encode).

Comment: @MarkAdler It doesn't accept an empty string, nor any character other than a-z or A-Z (not even digits). I added the encodings of a single space, `M`, `MM` and `MN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit I think it's [LZF](https://github.com/ning/compress/wiki/LZFFormat) with the following differences to your observations:

- The magic header and indication of compressed vs uncompressed has been removed in your example (not too surprising if it's embedded in a file).
- You took the block length as one byte, but it is two bytes and big-endian, so the prior 0x00 is part of the length, which still works.

Comment: Yes! You seem to have hit the nail on the head. I suspect it is one or more LZF-compressed files in a container.

Answer (score 1):

Could be NTFS compression, which is [LZNT1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj665697.aspx).  This idea is supported by the platform and the apparent 2-byte structure, along with the byte-alignment of the actual data.

> The following elements are specific to this algorithm.
>
> Chunks: Segments of data that are compressed, uncompressed, or that denote the end of the buffer.
>
> Chunk header: The header for a compressed or uncompressed chunk of data.
>
> Flag bytes: A bit flag whose bits, read from low order to high order, specify the formats of the data elements that follow. For example, bit 0 corresponds to the first data element, bit 1 to the second, and so on. If the bit corresponding to a data element is set, the element is a 2-byte compressed word; otherwise, it is a 1-byte literal value.
>
> Flag group: A flag byte followed by zero or more data elements, each of which is a single literal byte or a 2-byte compressed word.

Comment: You may be onto something. I'll look into it.

Comment: I looked deeper into the file, and it seems that not just the string, but the whole file (or parts of it at least) are compressed using some LZ variant. However, it isn't LZNT1, as that starts with a 16-bit chunk header indicating the size of the chunk. As seen in the screenshot, the first 16-bit value is `1`, and the chunk is most certainly not 1 byte long. But I'll keep on searching. +1 for the suggestion.

Comment: @Virtlink: There might be an application-specific header on the front as well.  If you scan through, do any of the bytes seem reasonable for a chunk size?

Comment: I can't find anything that indicates a chunk size, nor any header or border-like structures at repeating intervals (e.g. every 4K). However, I've been able to reverse-engineer the encoding used, but I don't recognize it and can't find anything on it. Please see my heavily updated post.